# Windows 10 Mail not marking emails as read

Tags: windows-10, email, windows-mail

I have just set up windows 10 mail to use both my gmail and yahoo mail accounts. However, when I look at an email in the Mail app, it does not mark them as read (for either account).

Is there a fix for this?

Thanks

Comment: If you mark the emails as read does it fix the issue? or doe it not mark them as read when you do that?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply, right clicking and marking as read does the job, it's just not when I actually read the email normally.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to mail app, Setting > Reading Pane > "Mark item as read" section.
2. There you can select how you want the mail app to know when any mail is read, either by:

   - marking it as read on selection change, or
   - marking it as read if mail is viewed by more than 5 (or any) seconds